# Google Spanner's Availability

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

In a multi-region configuration of Spanner, what happens to read-write requests (and strong read requests) if all replicas in both read-write regions go down? What happens to read-only requests?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: assume that reads will fail.

Long answer: Its hard to say, as it depends on where the read originates, and the type of read. Note that from the application's point of view, it cannot send a request directly to a read replica.

Reads from a region close to where the read-write replicas are located will most likely fail, as they may be directed to the RW replicas.

For reads originating from a region where there is a working read only replica, it depends on the type of the read:

- Strong read requests will fail (as they need to contact a RW replica).
- Exact stale reads for a timestamp when the RW instance was up will succeed (up to the 1hr version GC timeout)
- Bounded stale read requests will succeed until the time bound is greater than the period for which the RW replicas are down.

Comment: Is there any publicly available information on how frequently this happens, e.g., documentation on outages per service (e.g. Spanner) per region?

Comment: The public information on outages is the cloud platform status historical incident list:
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-spanner